# Table cells with vertically spread contents

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, lists, paragraphs

I have been using lists inside `multicols` for a "condensed" typesetting of lists of short items. However, I do not like what happens if a page break occurs inside, and I couldn't find a way to automatically force a page break before `multicols` if it cannot fit onto the current page.

So I have been thinking about using some kind of a table environment to typeset a single-row table with lists in cells.

However, I would like to make the lists in cells spread vertically so that their tops and bottoms be aligned (except when this wouldn't make sense), like columns in `multicols`.

So far I do not see how to make a table whose height is determined by the maximal natural height of its cells, and where I could make the contents of any cell spread vertically to align top and bottom baselines. Is it possible? How?

This might look like not a very natural thing to do, but I am used to the behaviour of lists in `multicols`, and I would like to avoid situations where, despite having the same number of items, the bottoms are not aligned because of accumulation of minor height differences.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, you have a 3-column list that is does not fit in the page:

[image: Mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
%\begin{table}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\item foo \item bar \item baz
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols} 
%\end{table}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

So you want is pass to the next page. The solution is as simple as put in a `table` or `figure` float to move the whole list to  the next page (Example: uncomment lines 6 and 20 of the above MWE *et voilá*. Of course, this can move more o less text after the list  to before of the list, to avoid gaps due to the premature page break.

If this is a problem, then you can use the `[H`] option for the float (need the `float` package)  or simpler, use any non-float box, for example `\parbox{\linewidth}{your multicols here}`.

Personally, I indeed will use the float without any option,  even if the list move out far of the logical order, because numbered captions and cross references exist just for this cases while the alternative is redesign the text or allow a horrible gap much worse that allow the page break within the list.

Comment: Thanks, `\parbox` seems to do what I need. In my case I usually have a list in 2-3 columns and 2-3 rows, so I do not want it to float away.

Comment: I didn't try `\parbox` with `multicols` because I had an impression that it could not work: [*Prevent page break when using multicols at end of page*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637686), [*Avoid page break for multicols*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366109), [*filbreak and multicols*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422286).

Comment: @Alexey  I guess than most people want list a part  of the main text, but consider that if the list is unbreakable list soon or later will produce an ugly gap, and then is where treat  it like a table or figure, beside the main text, could have (or not) some sense. If you use a float, change of mind is only change `[h]` to `[H]`.

Comment: Strangely, putting `multicols` inside `parbox` or `minipage` affects vertical spacing before and after. Do you know by any chance how to deal with it?

Comment: @Alexey No and yes. Use `\fbox{}` to frame these boxes and you can see better: if there a blank line (=\par) before and after the box, the outer space is by default the same that between paragraphs (i.e, controlled only by \parskip) but may also change by  the vertical align of the box (compare with options `[t]`,`[b]` and `[c]` in both cases) whereas inner spacing added by multicols is lost in the minipage but not in the `\parbox`. Note that a float with `[H]` will have another spacing rules but they cannot be tested in this way.